# Oracle SQL query with two date filters doesn't return value

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this table in oracle :

```
CREATE TABLE "MY_FOO"."SG_MEM" 
   (    "SG_MEM_OBJ" NUMBER, 
    "SG_OBJ_NUM" NUMBER, 
    "SUB_NUM" NUMBER, 
    "F_DATE" DATE, 
    "X_DATE" DATE
   }
```

then i insert initial data :

```
insert into SG_MEM  (  SG_MEM_OBJ ,
                        SG_OBJ_NUM , 
                        SUB_NUM ,
                        F_DATE , 
                        X_DATE  ) 
            values  (
                        24242,
                        33333,
                        2001936,
                        SYSDATE,
                        TO_DATE('2019/10/19 10:43:12', 'yyyy/mm/dd HH:MI:SS'));
```

Values now in the table look like this:

```
INSERT
INTO EXPORT_TABLE
  (
    SG_MEM_OBJ ,
    SG_OBJ_NUM,
    SUB_NUM ,
    F_DATE ,
    X_DATE
  )
  VALUES
  (
    24242,33333,2001936,
    to_date('20-October-2016','DD-MON-RRRR'),
    to_date('19-October-2019','DD-MON-RRRR')
  );
```

Now my problem is that I try to fetch this data like this :

```
select SG_MEM_OBJ ,
                  SG_OBJ_NUM ,
                  SUB_NUM ,
                  F_DATE ,
                  X_DATE  
 from SG_MEM  
 where  SG_MEM_OBJ =2001936 
and F_DATE  <=  TO_DATE('16/10/24 8:10:12', 'yyyy/mm/dd HH:MI:SS')
and X_DATE  > TO_DATE('16/10/24 8:10:12', 'yyyy/mm/dd HH:MI:SS');
```

It doesn't fetch the only single record , if I comment this line :

```
 and F_DATE  <=  TO_DATE('16/10/24 8:10:12', 'yyyy/mm/dd HH:MI:SS')
```

it does fetch it.
I can't see the problem here .

Comment: Well, the October 20th date you have there is later (read: bigger) than the October 16th date in your where clayse...

Comment: thanks, i mixed the dates ...

Comment: `'16/10/24 8:10:12'` does not match the pattern: `'yyyy/mm/dd HH:MI:SS'`

Answer (score 1):

Even with apparently consistent dates, the way you are converting string to dates - particularly in your final query - is not right. For example when you do:

```
and F_DATE  <=  TO_DATE('16/10/24 8:10:12', 'yyyy/mm/dd HH:MI:SS')
```

You don't get the date you expect. You're passing a two-digit year with a 4-digit year mask in the format model; you can see what that actually produces with:

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';
select TO_DATE('16/10/24 8:10:12', 'yyyy/mm/dd HH:MI:SS') from dual;

TO_DATE('16/10/248:1
--------------------
 0016-10-24 08:10:12
```

So you're looking for values before year 0016, rather than before 2016. You should be doing:

```
and F_DATE  <=  TO_DATE('2016/10/24 8:10:12', 'yyyy/mm/dd HH24:MI:SS')
```

You should probably be using `HH24` instead of `HH` as well, so I've used that. All of your times will currently be AM, which might be what you want here, but it's still better to be explicit.

You could use an ANSI timestamp literal (cast to a date if the column is indexed) instead if the value you're searching on is fixed. You *could* also still use two-digit years in your string if you use an `RR` model for the year, instead of `YYYY` or `YY`; but it's still better to use four-digit years to avoid potential confusion.